# Cors error when sending data from front-end client side react component to node.js server

Tags: node.js, reactjs, cors

I am attempting to send data from my client side react component below to my node.js server. Within my console it shows the data is being passed through from client side to server. However, I am getting the following cors error:

> Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://localhost:4000/. (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing). Status code: 200.

I am not sure why I am still getting this as I have required and implemented cors below, as well as put res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*"); in the post request.

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thank you :)

**UPDATE**

I solved the issue by enabling the cors middleware app.use(cors())

node server.js file

```
const express = require("express"); 
const cors = require("cors");
const app = express(); 

const port = 4000;

app.post("/", cors(), (req, res) => {
  res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  const emailInfo = req.body.emailUserInput;
  console.log(emailInfo);

  // sendgrid details //

  require("dotenv").config();
  const sgMail = require("@sendgrid/mail");
  const apikey = process.env.SENDGRID_API_KEY;
  sgMail.setApiKey(apikey);
  const msg = {
    to: emailInfo,
    from: "email",
    subject: "Sending with Twilio SendGrid is Fun",
    text: "and easy to do anywhere, even with Node.js",
    html: "<strong>and easy to do anywhere, even with Node.js</strong>",
  };

  // email sending logic //

  //ES8
  (async () => {
    try {
      await sgMail.send(msg);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);

      if (error.response) {
        console.error(error.response.body);
      }
    }
  })();
});

app.listen(port, hostname, () => {
  console.log(`Server running at http://${hostname}:${port}/`);
});
```

client-side react component

```
import "../StyleComponents/CreateEvent.css";
import { useState } from 'react';
import { db } from '../firebase';
import { uid } from "uid";
import { set, ref } from "firebase/database";
import Header from "./Header";
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';
import { getStorage, ref as sref, uploadBytes } from "firebase/storage";
import PlacesAutocomplete from 'react-places-autocomplete';
import { geocodeByAddress, getLatLng } from 'react-places-autocomplete';
import axios from 'axios';

function CreateEvent() {

    // store user inputs in state //

    const [titleUserInput, setTitleUserInput] = useState('');
    const [dateUserInput, setDateUserInput] = useState('');
    const [timeUserInput, setTimeUserInput] = useState('');
    const [address, setAddress] = useState('');
    const [setCoordinates] = useState({
        lat: null,
        lng: null,
    })
    const [headerUserInput, setHeaderUserInput] = useState('');
    const [detailsUserInput, setDetailsUserInput] = useState('');
    const [lengthUserInput, setLengthUserInput] = useState('');
    const [emailUserInput, setEmailUserInput] = useState('');
    const [userSubmit, setUserSubmit] = useState('');
    const [error, setError] = useState(false);

    // Create a root reference for storing event photos //

    const storage = getStorage();

    // handle changing user input data //

    const handleTitleChange = (e) => {
        setTitleUserInput(e.target.value);
    }
    const handleDateChange = (e) => {
        setDateUserInput(e.target.value);
    }
    const handleTimeChange = (e) => {
        setTimeUserInput(e.target.value);
    }

    const handleSelect = async (value) => {
        const results = await geocodeByAddress(value);
        const latLng = await getLatLng(results[0]);
        setAddress(value);
        setCoordinates(latLng);
    }

    const handleDetailsChange = (e) => {
        setDetailsUserInput(e.target.value);
    }
    const handleLengthChange = (e) => {
        setLengthUserInput(e.target.value);
    }
    const handleHeaderChange = (e) => {
        // Create a root reference for storing event photos //
        setHeaderUserInput(e.target.files[0]);
    }

    const handleEmailChange = (e) => {
        setEmailUserInput(e.target.value);
    }

    const navigate = useNavigate();

       // make call to the backend database to send email user input data //

    const url = 'http://localhost:4000';

    const getEmailInput = () => {
        axios.post(url, {emailUserInput}).then((res) => {
            console.log(res);
        }).catch(console.log('error'));
    }

    // submit user data to database with unique ID for each event //

    const writeToDataBase = () => {
        let uuid = uid()
        if (titleUserInput.length === 0 || dateUserInput.length === 0 || timeUserInput.length === 0 || address.length === 0 || emailUserInput.length === 0) {
            setError(true);
        }
        if (titleUserInput && dateUserInput && timeUserInput && address && emailUserInput) {
            const storageRef = sref(storage, uuid);
            set(ref(db, `/${uuid}`), {
                EventPhoto: headerUserInput,
                EventTitle: titleUserInput,
                EventDate: dateUserInput,
                EventTime: timeUserInput,
                EventLength: lengthUserInput,
                EventLocation: address,
                EventDetails: detailsUserInput,
            });
            getEmailInput('');
            setUserSubmit('');
            uploadBytes(storageRef, headerUserInput).then(() => {
                navigate(`/EventCreated/${uuid}`);
            });
        }
    }
  
    return (
           <>
            < Header />
    <div className="event-creation-container">
            <h1>Create a New Event</h1>
                <form>
            <div className="event-name-container event-input">
        <label for="eventTitle">Name of Event<span>*</span></label>
                        <input type="text" id="EventTitle" value={titleUserInput} onChange={handleTitleChange} /> 
                        {error && titleUserInput === '' ?
                            <label id="form-validation-label">Event name must be filled</label> : ""}
                    </div>
                    <div className="date-time-length">
            <div className="date-input-container event-input">      
                <label for="Date">Date<span>*</span></label>
                            <input type="date" id="EventDate" value={dateUserInput} onChange={handleDateChange} />   
                            {error && dateUserInput === '' ? <label id="form-validation-label">Event date must be filled</label>: ""}
                    </div>    
            <div className="time-input-container event-input">       
                <label for="Time">Time<span>*</span></label>
                <input id="EventTime" type="time" name="time" timezone="timezone" value={timeUserInput} onChange={handleTimeChange} /> 
                        </div>
                        {error && timeUserInput === '' ? <label id="form-validation-label">Event time must be filled</label> : ""}
                    <div className="length-input-container event-input">
                        <label for="Length">Length</label>
                        <input id="EventLength" type="text" value={lengthUserInput} onChange={handleLengthChange} />
                        </div>
                    </div>
            <div className="location-input-container event-input">
                        <label for="Location">Location<span>*</span></label>
                        <PlacesAutocomplete onChange={setAddress} value={address} onSelect={handleSelect}
                        >
                            {({ getInputProps, suggestions, getSuggestionItemProps, loading }) => (       
                                <div>
                                    <input id="EventLocation" {...getInputProps()} />
                                    <div className="location-suggestions">
                                        {loading ? <div>...loading</div> : null}
                                        {suggestions.map((suggestion) => {
                                            const style = {
                                                backgroundColor: suggestion.active ? "#41b6e6" : "#fff"
                                            };
                                            return <div {...getSuggestionItemProps(suggestion, { style })}>{suggestion.description}</div>
                                        })}
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            )}
                            </PlacesAutocomplete>
                    </div> 
                    {error && address ==='' ? <label id="form-validation-label">Event location must be filled</label> : ""}
            <div className="details-input-container event-input">
        <label for="Event_Details">Event Details</label>
                    <textarea type="text" id="EventDetails" value={detailsUserInput} onChange={handleDetailsChange} />
                    </div>
                    <div className="header-input-container event-input">
             <div className="upload-image-flex-container">
        <label for="header_image">Upload Header Image  (optional)</label>
                        <input className="upload-input" type="file" id="
                        EventImage" name="filename" accept="image/png, image/jpeg" onChange={handleHeaderChange} />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div className="orangizer-email-container">
                        <label for="organizer-email">Organizer's Email<span>*</span></label>
                        <p>The event page link will be sent to your email</p>
                        <input id="EventEmail" type="email" name="email" value={emailUserInput} onChange={handleEmailChange} />
                        {error && emailUserInput === '' ? <label id="form-validation-label">Event organizer's email must be entered</label> : ""}
            </div>
                <div className="create-event-btn-container">
                        <button className="event-create-button" type="button" value={userSubmit} onClick={writeToDataBase}>Create Event</button>
                </div>
        </form>  
    </div>
</>
)}

export default CreateEvent;
```

Comment: @jub0bs thanks! maybe if I host my server on heroku instead of localhost it will work?

Comment: No. Start by dropping that `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header from your request. That header is a _response_ header, not a _request_ header. Then try again. Also, familiarise yourself with CORS by reading https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS carefully.

Comment: @jub0bs I changed res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*"); to req.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*"); ... still does not work.

Comment: _Remove_ `req.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "");` altogether... And read that MDN Web Docs I shared.

Answer (score -1):

Your issue here may be the browser sending out a CORS preflight request which is then followed by your POST request. This is an OPTIONS request sent automatically which is where it is expecting to get the CORS headers from. See [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Preflight_request).

Currently even though you've implemented CORS on your post endpoint, it's not catching that preflight request which is likely what you need to do. The 'cors' npm package describes that on their [page](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors#enabling-cors-pre-flight). Implementing this should then allow the browser to recognise the origin so you no longer get errors back.